# FileReader: 'read' example

Tags: java, file, file-io

The `FileReader` class is used to perform I/O on characters.

I try to read a file that is placed in directory and passed as argument in the FileReader constructor. The file contains some character values like `abcd`.

When i try to read from the `FileReader` with `read` method, it returns values in ASCII, whereas `FileReader` is used for characters. Why does this happen? If unicde concept is taken, then when we read characters from a file then it must convert in characters. But this does not happen.

Data in file "xyz.txt" is "abcd".

Code:

```
File h=new File("d:/xyz.txt");
FileReader j=new FileReader(l);
for(int i=0;i<h.length;i++)
{
  System.out.println(j.read());
}
```

I want it to print "abcd". Instead it prints ASCII values, why?

Comment: What is the data in the file ?

Comment: and what you want to do?

Comment: sir plz give answer why you depost it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the contract of [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29) says it should. You could use `read(char[] buf)` to read characters directly.

Comment: It is documented in the link I posted: It reads a character from that file and returns the integer representation of it, which is probably UTF-8.

Comment: @bimalchawla - Read [the link in the answer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29). `read` returns an `int` type. Not a `char` type. So `System.out.println` prints what it gets. i.e. an `int`.